# Using arrays to print out the averages of the numbers in the array and the lowest number in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program that creates a `HomeworkGrades()` class that stores the homework grades of 8 chapters into an array of `doubles`. I need to create a constructor that takes an array as input and copies the contents of the array and copies it into the classes array. Finally in my `main()` class I need to print out the average of the scores in the array and the lowest value in the array. I think I created my `HomeworkGrades()` class correctly, I just can't figure out how to call the correct methods to make the values print to the screen.

Here is my `main()` class...

```
package classwork_7_1;

public class ClassWork_7_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90};
        double lowChap = grades[0];

        System.out.println(average(grades[]));
        System.out.println(lowChap(lowChap[]));
    }
}
```

Here is my `HomeworkGrades()` class...

```
package classwork_7_1;

public class HomeworkGrades {
    private double[] grades = new double[8];

    public HomeworkGrades(double[] grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public double average(double[] grades) {
        int chap = 8;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
            sum += i;
        double average = sum / chap;

        return average;
    }

    public double lowChap(double[] grades) {
        double minValue = grades[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = grades[i];

                return minValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a class `HomeworkGrades` but you never instantiate it in `main` (by calling `new HomeworkGrades`), doing so would be a good start.

Comment: @MegaBluejay, sure...anything would help, I just can't use `.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in these lines:

```
double lowChap = grades[0];

System.out.println(average(grades[]));
System.out.println(lowChap(lowChap[]));
```

`lowChap` is a single `double` and you're trying to pass `lowChap[]` into `lowChap()` which accepts an `Array` of doubles, and needs to be invoked on a `HomeWorkGrades` object. Clearly this will not work. Instead, you must create an `object` of type `HomeWorkGrades` and pass `grades` into the constructor and then call the methods on that object. In which case you could remove the arguments in your methods and just use `this.grades`:

```
HomeWorkGrades hw = new HomeWorkGrades(grades);

System.out.println(hw.average());
System.out.println(hw.lowChap());
```

---

So in your methods you would have:

```
public double average(){
    int chap = 8;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<grades.length; i++)
        sum+=grades[i];
    double average = sum / chap;

    return average;   
}
public double lowChap(){    
    double minValue = grades[0];

    for(int i=0;i<grades.length;i++){
        if(grades[i] < minValue)
           minValue = grades[i];
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

Note that in `average` I changed `sum += i;` to `sum+= grades[i];` to add the grade at index `i` to `sum` instead of just `i`.

***Output:***

```
77.575
33.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that below code doesn't handle the case of an empty `grades` array.

```
double min = Arrays.stream(grades).min().getAsDouble();
double average = Arrays.stream(grades).average().getAsDouble();
```